# Fitting a product of two distributions to data when one distribution is known

Tags: normal-distribution, fitting

I have data that I would like to model with a product distribution (of two independent random variables). The product distribution is being adopted because there is reason to believe that the variable being measured empirically is a ratio of two variables (or the product of one variable and the reciprocal of the other), and it is the numerator and denominator of the ratio that are of interest.

I have a candidate distribution for one function (say fx(x) in the image below from Wikipedia is a normal distribution with unknown mean and variance), and the data.. and would like to fit the second function non-parametrically (without assuming a second candidate distribution).

It seems to me that one way to do it is to bin the data and then choose the center of each bin to create a vector of z-values where the product distribution value has been estimated, and then with the right choice of z and x, the final equation in the image below becomes a set of linear equations with fy(z/x) as the unknowns.. does this sound right ?

Are there better ways to go about this ?

Not a homework problem. Thanks !

[image: Product distribution pdf]

Comment: Is there any motivation behind this modeling strategy?

Comment: Thanks, added an edit. Yes, there is a theoretical motivation.

Comment: You might find it simpler to model the logarithms of your data, provided they are positive.

Comment: @whuber, thank you. I guess your point is that the log of the product distribution is the convolution of the distribution of log(x) and log(y) ? I have to think about whether that makes it easier.. since that convolution integral is also quite similar to the one for the product distribution in the last line of the Wikipedia image ?

Comment: It tends to be a simpler integral, especially because in practice the logs of the numerator and denominator of a natural ratio will tend to have simpler distributions (such as Normal ones, or at least symmetric ones).  The convolution also enjoys nice linearity properties, making analysis easier. In particular, it makes it far easier to use moment-based procedures.